# Magento 1.9.1: Error when loading new email template

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I tried to add an email template in magento

system > transactional emails > add new template.

i can't click on the dropdown and the rest of the page won't load.

I went into system.log and found this

```
2015-06-17T07:48:44+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Email/Helper/Data.php): failed to open stream:
No such file or directory  in /home/gedditsg/public_html/dev/profient/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94 

2015-06-17T07:48:44+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Email/Helper/Data.php' for inclusion
(include_path='/home/gedditsg/public_html/dev/profient/app/code/local:/home/gedditsg/public_html/dev/profient/app/code/community:/home/gedditsg/public_html/dev/profient/app/code/core:/home/gedditsg/public_html/dev/profient/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')
in /home/gedditsg/public_html/dev/profient/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

I don't have any directory in folder called Email in /Mage

I disabled all plugins that I have installed before this to see if there were any errors from there but still it didn't work.

Need help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code or XML config you are referencing this helper, so I'd track down said code/config and remove it.

Alternatively you could just cheat and drop in an empty helper class:

```
Mage_Email_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract { }
```

Comment: Sorry. but where can i add this class in? the exact directory and file? im quite new to this. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway Thanks. Found where I'm supposed to insert the class in.

app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/data.php

Thanks!